# Listing only the missing info that does not match file 1 from file two

Tags: bash, shell

File 1 is the `/etc/hosts` file with an output below

```
10.0.0.1     router1
10.0.0.2     router2
10.0.0.3     router3
10.0.0.4     router4
```

file two id a rancid database in `/usr/local/rancid/var/devices/router.db` with output like below:

```
router1:cisco:up
router2:cisco:up
```

I want to be able to run a script that could look for the hostnames only `routerx` and find which ones have not been added to the `router.bd` with `routerx:cisco:up`.

So the output that I am looking for with the above example would be:

print Missing routers

```
router3
router4
```

end

Could you assist with something or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F '[: ]+' 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} !($NF in a) {print $NF}' router.db hosts
router3
router4
```

**Explanation:**

```
-F '[: ]+'  # Use custom field separator as 1 or more of colon or space
FNR==NR     # for first file populate an array `a` with key as $1
next        # keep reading 1st file till EOF is reached
!($NF in a) # from 2nd file execute {...} if last fieild in NOT in array a
{print $NF} # print last field from hosts file
```

Comment: Nice! These awk one liners always condensate much information in a clear and short way

Comment: @fedorqui Well, it's neat. But I'm not sure I would agree that the `FNR==NR` trick should be described as 'clear'. :)

Comment: @ccarton: That is standard awk way to read/compare data between 2 files.

Comment: Oh, I have no doubt that it is.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
routerdb="/usr/local/rancid/var/devices/router.db"

while read _ router; do
  grep -q "^$router:" $routerdb || echo "Missing: $router"
done < /etc/hosts
```

Comment: note you can skip the awk indirection by saying `while read _ router; do ... done < /etc/hosts`. `_` will contain the first word and `$router` the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following way:-

```
awk -F'\t' {'print $2'} /etc/hosts > temp.txt
awk -F':'  {'print $2'} /usr/local/rancid/var/devices/router.db > temp1.txt
cat temp.txt | while read a
do
     i=`grep -c $a temp1.txt`
     if [ $i -eq 0 ]
     then
          echo $a
     fi
done
```

This will print router3 & router4..

Comment: `cat file | awk '...'` is better written as `awk '...' file`. Also, `cat file | while ...` is better written as `while read ... done< file`. Finally, the `grep` condition could be improved: `if $(grep -q "$a" temp1.txt) ...`

Comment: if $(grep -q "$a" temp1.txt) - i see grep -q returns 0 on first match, So "if  $(0)" says that the condition is false and it exits the if loop. So in this case we should us if !(..) or something like it.  I remember if tru is 1 and false is 0.   Correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

`diff` is usually a good choice when comparing files. A complete solution could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ROUTERDB=/usr/local/rancid/var/devices/router.db 
HOSTS=/etc/hosts

# use a temporary directory:
DIR=$(mktemp -d)
cd ${DIR}

# write first field of router.db in one file, using : as delimiter:
awk -F: '{ print $1 }' ${ROUTERDB} > routerdb
# write second field of hosts in the other:
awk '{ print $2 }' ${HOSTS} > hosts

# compare the two files, select only lines not in 
# router.db, and remove the + sign at the beginning:
echo Missing routers
diff -u routerdb hosts | grep "^+[^+]" | tr -d "+"
echo end

# remove temporary directory:
rm -rf ${DIR}
```